# how to shift element on click visible section in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have few Items in `array` .I want to show those items in `li` or list .

```
const data = [
  "xahsdhas asd",
  "222234 asdasdas asdasd asd asdasdsad",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5"
];
```

But the condition is that I have only width of `1000px`.I want to put as much as element in container.Rest element I have to put below `more link`(as a dropdown).

so i am able to put as much element in container or visible section rest I put in more section.

It is working fine see below screen show.

[image]

But I am facing one issue when user click on any `more items` .it should go to visible section (but condition is same  visible area is width is 1000 px) . so one the item from visible section goes to `more menu section`.

Example :

1. If user click on `3` (first item from more item) . `3` item goes to visible section .and one of the item from visible section move to `more item section`

**expected out** after click `3` item.

[image]

Another example if I click to element `4`
**BELOW IS EXPECTED OUTPUT .**
[image]

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hellman-hswdl?file=/src/App.js:108-148

```
const moveToVisibleArea = () => {
    console.log("====");
  };

  const getTabs = () => {
    const { tabWidth, dimension, total } = state;
    var visible = [],
      avaiable = total,
      hidden = [];
    if (defaultState) {
      return {
        visible,
        hidden
      };
    }
    data.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (avaiable - dimension[index] > 0) {
        visible.push(element);
        avaiable = avaiable - dimension[index];
      } else {
        hidden.push(element);
      }
    });
    return {
      visible,
      hidden
    };
  };
  const { visible = [], hidden = [] } = getTabs();
  return (
    <>
      dummy::
      <ul id="dummy">
        {visible.length === 0 &&
          hidden.length === 0 &&
          data.map((el, i) => (
            <li ref={elRefs[i]} key={i}>
              {el}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
      visible::
      <ul id="visible">
        {visible.map((el, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{el}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <br />
      more Item (hidden . user can click below item to move to visible
      container)::
      <br />
      <ul id="hidden">
        {hidden.map((el, i) => (
          <li key={i} onClick={moveToVisibleArea}>
            {el}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width and tabs bit it a little unclear to me from your question, but it seems like you want a sort of "move to front" list to move items from the "hidden" section to the "visible" section. You neglected to describe how an element from the visible area it "kicked out", so implementing a "move to front" list seems the most intuitive. Another way to think about this is it being a sort of pseudo "Least Recently Used" used list... the item at the end of the visible area is the least recently interacted item.

```
const moveToVisibleArea = (index) => () => {
  setData(data => {
    const newData = data.slice();
    return [newData.splice(index, 1), ...newData];
  });
};
```

Shallow copy the array using `slice` and then splice out the element at the specific index and return it into the zeroth element of the new array and shallow copy the remaining array.

When mapping the array, use `slice` twice, once each for the visible and hidden areas.

```
visible::
<ul id="visible">
  {data.slice(0, 2).map((el, i) => (
    <li key={el}>{el}</li>
  ))}
</ul>
<br />
more Item (hidden . user can click below item to move to visible
container)::
<br />
<ul id="hidden">
  {data.slice(2).map((el, i) => (
    <li key={el} onClick={moveToVisibleArea(2 + i)}>
      {el}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Here the first two elements (indices) are considered the visible area while the remaining elements are mapped into the hidden area. Use the mapped index ***plus*** the number if visible elements to get the index offset for the element to "move to the front" of the list and make visible.

#### Update

I forgot to mention that since you are mutating the underlying array that you are mapping that you can't use the index as the React key. In my code examples I just used the array elements since they are unique and intrinsic to each element, but this breaks down with duplicates. The best thing to do is to assign a GUID to each element that persists for the life of the element.

[image: Edit how-to-shift-element-on-click-visible-section-in-react-js]

Comment: @thanks drew for .answer.  I have query ..actually I am planning to use above logic in my real example will it work ?

Comment: if you see in jquery code  (HTML ) `ct12current` class append to second last element , but it show in front .

Comment: right now it is not showing in front . any idea will it work ?  I don't think it will work

Comment: I think we need to check whether coming element width , again calculate the width of visible section .on the basic of coming element width I need to pop out "visible section element"

Comment: any idea ? any `npm package will help me` ?

Comment: @user944513 I don't know, it's difficult to say. I don't understand the Jquery example and I don't understand your codesandbox example. Nothing seems to work in either example from what I can tell, but I don't understand what they are supposed to do if they are doing anything. It looks like you are implementing drop-down menus. Generally you don't mix Jquery and React, ***at all***, since they solve similar UI problems but in completely orthogonal ways.

Comment: @user944513 Sorry, but I feel like one would need quite a bit more context for your follow-on questions. It sounds like my answer may've resolved a small piece of your overall issue(s). You've enough rep that I probably don't need to say this, but I will anyway: go ahead and ask another SO question about one of your other more specific issues. If anything you'll get more eyes on it more quickly in all likelihood. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68263981/how-to-show-selected-item-in-react-js