# how to show selected item in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of items (Example names). I am trying to show the selected item in the list.
.Selected items have a `selected` class which will add a border to that element.

```
.selected {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

selected Item decide with a variable `const selectedItem = 1;` if it `1` it will select `second` item .If `const selectedItem = 0;` it will select first element.

**Problem & statement**

1. I have wrapper div `className="container"` which has width `200px`. It will contain as much as list element it can. It depends on Item width.

Example **list Item** (see example 1 it only shows three Items as all text are  small.)

```
const data = [
  { title: "xahsdha" },
  { title: "hello" },
  { title: "hessllo" },
  { title: "hesslssslo" },
  { title: "navveiii" }
];
```

[image]

Example 2 with new data: See Item first text is big. It shows only one item.

```
const data = [
  { title: "xahsdhaadasdasdasdass" },
  { title: "hello" },
  { title: "hessllo" },
  { title: "hesslssslo" },
  { title: "navveiii" }
];
```

[image]

**Issue**:

I am not able to select that item that goes outside the container.

Example **given data**

```
const data = [
  { title: "xahsdh" },
  { title: "hello" },
  { title: "hessllo" },
  { title: "hesslssslo" },
  { title: "navveiii" }
];
```

if I give **const selectedItem = 1;**

**my output and expected out are the same**. see I am able to show selected Item
[image]

but if I give **const selectedItem = 3;**  with same data set
**my output is this**

[image]

**But the expected output is this**
[image]

**can we move forward the hidden element if it is selected ?**

**Scenario 2**

1. we need to take care of hidden element width also .so selected item width depends on how many items I will show in the container.

example if we pass `const selectedItem = 3`;
with this data set

```
const data = [
  { title: "xahsdh" },
  { title: "hello" },
  { title: "hessllo" },
  { title: "hesslsssloasdasdasdasdasdsa" },
  { title: "navveiii" }
];
```

The expected output is this
[image]

is this functionality feasible?

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hellman-hswdl?file=/src/App.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { createRef, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
const data = [
  { title: "xahsdh" },
  { title: "hello" },
  { title: "hessllo" },
  { title: "hesslssslo" },
  { title: "navveiii" }
];
const selectedItem = 1;
export default function App() {
  const arrLength = data.length;
  const [defaultState, setDefaultState] = React.useState(true);

  const elRefs = useMemo(
    () => Array.from({ length: data.length }).map(() => createRef()),
    []
  );
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    total: 0,
    tabWidth: 0,
    dimension: {}
  });
  const ulRef = useRef(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setDimention();
  }, []);

  const setDimention = () => {
    let total = ulRef.current.offsetWidth,
      dimension = {},
      tabWidth = 0;
    console.log(total);
    elRefs.forEach((item, i) => {
      dimension[i] = item.current?.offsetWidth || 0;
      tabWidth += item.current?.offsetWidth || 0;
    });
    console.log({
      total,
      dimension,
      tabWidth
    });
    setDefaultState(false);
    setState({
      total,
      dimension,
      tabWidth
    });
  };

  const getTabs = () => {
    const { tabWidth, dimension, total } = state;
    var visible = [],
      avaiable = total,
      hidden = [];
    if (defaultState) {
      return {
        visible,
        hidden
      };
    }
    data.forEach((element, index) => {
      if (avaiable - dimension[index] > 0) {
        visible.push(element);
        avaiable = avaiable - dimension[index];
      } else {
        hidden.push(element);
      }
    });
    return {
      visible,
      hidden
    };
  };
  const { visible = [], hidden = [] } = getTabs();
  return (
    <div className="container" ref={ulRef}>
      <ul id="dummy">
        {visible.length === 0 &&
          hidden.length === 0 &&
          data.map((el, i) => (
            <li
              className={i === selectedItem ? "selected" : ""}
              ref={elRefs[i]}
              key={i}
            >
              {el.title}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
      <ul id="visible">
        {visible.map((el, i) => (
          <li className={i === selectedItem ? "selected" : ""} key={i}>
            {el.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <ul id="hidden">
        {hidden.map((el, i) => (
          <li className="hide" key={i}>
            {el.title}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**NOTE & update**:I don't want scrollable  list . I want first priority given to "selected" item and if space available add other element in front .

Any suggestion ?

In jQuery it is possible .so sure whether we achieve this in react or not.I checked this jQuery example selected item is in last but still it come in view

https://codepen.io/naveennsit/pen/poPJOPM?editors=1010

Comment: maybe you can make the div horizontally scrollable, and then programmatically scroll to the element that is selected

Comment: @RishabhGupta I don't want to scroll list ..take a example if `selectedIndex=4`  .it will show element 3 (with multiple permutation  elem 1 + elm 2 ) or element  3 (elem 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the main issue here is figuring out which elements should be displayed when ***not*** rendering from the beginning.

I suggest computing the arrays of visible and hidden elements starting from the currently selected item, and a visible offset. First go in reverse and compute the visible/hidden elements moving towards the ***front*** of the array, then do a second loop starting from the element ***after*** the selected item moving towards the ***end*** of the array.

```
const getTabs = () => {
  const { dimension, total } = state;

  const visible = [];
  const hidden = [];

  let offset = 0;
  let available = total;

  if (!initialRender) {
    // check forward
    for (let i = selectedItem; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (available > dimension[i]) {
        visible.unshift(data[i]);
        available -= dimension[i];
      } else {
        hidden.unshift(data[i]);
        offset++;
      }
    }

    // check aft
    for (let i = selectedItem + 1; i < arrLength; i++) {
      if (available > dimension[i]) {
        visible.push(data[i]);
        available -= dimension[i];
      } else {
        hidden.push(data[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return {
    hidden,
    offset,
    visible
  };
};
```

When rendering the visible and hidden arrays, just compare the current mapped index + offset to the currently selected item index.

```
<ul id="visible">
  {visible.map((el, i) => (
    <li
      className={i + offset === selectedItem ? "selected" : ""}
      key={i}
    >
      {el.title}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
<ul id="hidden">
  {hidden.map((el, i) => (
    <li className="hide" key={i}>
      {el.title}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

[image: Edit how-to-show-selected-item-in-react-js]

#### EDIT

Since the idea is to have in the visible area, the currently selected item, and then only those elements from the array, from the beginning of the array, that still fit, also visible, we can modify the above solution to instead make the assumption the currently selected item will always fit.

First subtract the selected items size from the availability, then iterate from the beginning of the array. If the current index doesn't match the current selected index, push the current element into the visible array and subtract from the availability if it fits. If currently looking at the selected item, push it into the visible array.

For this algorithm and rendering I added a GUID to each item.

```
const data = [
  { title: "xahsdh", id: uuidV4() },
  { title: "hello", id: uuidV4() },
  { title: "hessllo", id: uuidV4() },
  { title: "hesslssslo", id: uuidV4() },
  { title: "navveiii", id: uuidV4() },
];

...

const getTabs = () => {
  const { dimension, total } = state;

  const visible = [];
  const hidden = [];

  const selectedIndex = data.findIndex((el) => el.id === selectedItem);
  if (!initialRender && selectedIndex !== -1) {
    let available = total - dimension[selectedIndex];

    data.forEach((el, i) => {
      if (i === selectedIndex) {
        visible.push(el);
        return;
      }
      if (available > dimension[i]) {
        visible.push(el);
        available -= dimension[i];
      } else {
        hidden.push(el);
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    hidden,
    visible
  };
};
```

When rendering check the GUID.

```
<ul id="visible">
  {visible.map((el, i) => (
    <li
      className={el.id === selectedItem ? "selected" : ""}
      key={el.id}
    >
      {el.title}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
<ul id="hidden">
  {hidden.map((el, i) => (
    <li className="hide" key={el.id}>
      {el.title}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

[image: Edit how-to-show-selected-item-in-react-js (forked)]

Comment: thankd @drew can you share codeshandbox link

Comment: Drew , I also tried my approach is different approach but it also works but fail in sometimes debuging ... https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-proskuriakova-tcr2t?file=/src/App.js:1631-1638

Comment: @user5711656 Ah sure, didn't realize you'd see this so quickly... was already in the process of adding my forked sandbox. Updated my answer with link.

Comment: drew , thanks but I think you are scrolling ... see my codesandbox. it is what i am looking https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-grass-8es2h?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=/src/App.js&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js

Comment: @user5711656 No, check again, no scrolling involved. I am shifting the visible "window" of elements that fit, if that is what you refer to.

Comment: see my codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-proskuriakova-tcr2t?file=/src/App.js  . try to change `selectedItem`

Comment: @user5711656 Right, I see you try to keep some visible regardless... but you haven't explained what or how you want to pick the items to keep in the visible. Is it keep all that will fit and replace the last N elements such that the selected replacement fits?

Comment: sorry , thanks for help but there is something wrong in your codesandbox . if I changed to  in your codesandbox from `0 to 3` const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState(3);... The expected output is `xahsdh` ,`hello` ,`hesslssslo`

Comment: but your output is `    hello ` `hessllo` `hesslssslo`

Comment: @user5711656 I don't mean to disagree with you, but your requirement "I want first priority given to "selected" item and if space available add other element in front ." is most certainly met in my answer. If you want something different then you need to be more specific. Need to be more specific about *what* other elements can be in front.

Comment: sorry drew , may be I am not able to explain . but I was saying  want first priority given to "selected"  ,,.. rest element are from `visible` array

Comment: I am trying I almost to reach my destination do you think it there anything wrong in my approach .https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-proskuriakova-tcr2t?file=/src/App.js:326-338

Comment: if you have any better idea , kindly share or better approach

Comment: @user5711656 Just so I understand, you want in the visible area, the currently selected item, and then only those elements from the array, from the beginning of the array, that still fit?

Comment: do you have any better approach or suggestion ?

Comment: can you share your apprach . my code is tittle buggi

Comment: @user5711656 Ok, took me a bit to think through the logic, but I believe I've an edit for what you're after.